Why do C generics use void * instead of macros?
As I understand it, the standard way to implement generic data types in C is with void pointers. However, an alternate approach would be to use macros. Here's an example implementation of a generic "Option" type using macros:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OPTION(T)                                                              \
  struct option_##T {                                                          \
    bool exists;                                                               \
    T data;                                                                    \
  };                                                                           \
  typedef struct option_##T option_##T;                                        \
  static inline bool is_some_##T(option_##T x) { return x.exists; }            \
  static inline bool is_none_##T(option_##T x) { return !x.exists; }

#define is_some(x) _Generic((x), option_int: is_some_int, option_char: is_some_char)(x)
#define is_none(x) _Generic((x), option_int: is_none_int, option_char: is_none_char)(x)

OPTION(int);
OPTION(char);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  option_int x = {.exists = true, .data=3};
  option_char y = {.exists = true, .data='a'};
  
  printf("x is some: %d\n", is_some(x));
  printf("y is some: %d\n", is_some(y));
  
  return 0;
}

The alternate approach would be to use a void * for the data entry. However, this would add an extra layer of indirection (while possibly saving on binary size). Is there a reason the void * approach is more common?

_Generic, void *, and macros all solve completely different problems. I don't know why you think "C generics use void * instead of macros". _Generic cannot distinguish what's behind a void *.

_Generic is in fact almost exclusively used in macros.

@user2357112 I'm not sure I understand your comment. As I understand it, the typical way of implementing an Option type would be to use a void * in the data entry. I am asking about the benefits of that approach vs. the one I described

Option types have nothing to do with generics. If you mean a single Option type that can hold an optional whatever, they need to use void * to be able to handle whatever type the user wants to use. Your is_some and is_none implementations can only handle types that were hardcoded into the macro definitions.

With void * you have a single implementation with a macro you have an implementation per type of each function, struct etc.  Macros relies on text manipulation and you need all kinds of tricks and problems to do simple things like loops, or even pass a comma as an argument.  If you use a lot of macros you end up with a custom language that looks very different than C.  This means you have to understand all the macros to figure out what is going on.  That can make such a code base hard to maintain.

For some possible insight, see my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C It compares/shows C versions with void * (and switch), a common struct (i.e. base class), and virtual function table.

I suggest you use the term "abstract data type" as "generic" implies the_Generic keyword which is used for type switching within a macro.

@AllanWind These terms are broader than just C language usage. "Abstract data type" as well as "type-generic programming" are two general computer science terms, none specific to C as such. "Generics" generally refers to type-generic programming, in the area of computer science.

Because _Generic is a relatively new feature. The "old school" way to do it was always with void pointers, either by creating a struct similar to your example but typically with an enum to mark the type represented. Or otherwise by type-specific callbacks as famously done by bsearch/qsort.
So void* is more common simply for historical reasons - there was no other way to do it back in the days. void* are becoming increasingly irrelevant these days, because they are dangerously type unsafe and there are better language features available now.
As for _Generic and soon-to-be-standardized typeof, there's a lot of different ways to use them. There's not really a need for wrapper structs/enums either. For example you can use them as "poor man's templates" - perhaps not recommended practice but quite powerful and type safe:
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPES_SUPPORTED(X) \
  X(int,  %d)              \
  X(char, %c)              \

#define PRINT(type, fmt)   \
void type##_print (type t) \
{                          \
  printf(#fmt "\n", t);    \
}
TYPES_SUPPORTED(PRINT)

#define GENERIC_PRINT(type, fmt) ,type: type##_print
#define print(x) \
  _Generic((x),  \
  default:0      \
  TYPES_SUPPORTED(GENERIC_PRINT) )(x)

int main() 
{
  int a = 123;
  char c = 'A';
  print(a);
  print(c);
}

This way to utilize "X macros" means that you can show all types supported into a list, no need to call individual macros as in your example. Instead you create one macro per use-case and then call the X macro list.
So this example creates one function int_print(int t) and one char_print(char t), printing the parameter using the correct format specifier.
We can then call these functions in turn from a type-generic print macro, where the _Generic association list has been baked into an X macro list too, reducing the need to type out each condition. The evil trick here is to put default: first and then begin each macro expansion with ,, since _Generic unlike array/enum declarations, initialization lists etc does not like trailing comma.

_Generic needs all supported types to be specified up front, though. It wouldn't be possible to implement something like bsearch or qsort with _Generic, since those have to be able to sort arbitrary user-defined types with arbitrary user-specified comparators.

@user2357112 It would be possible if you define the search/sort function as well as the callback using the above model. The downside is that you have to implement it yourself, but then we've all done that at some point.
