How to return an address of a const struct member in compliance to MISRA from a C function?
I have a C function that gets the address of a struct member and returns it as a void pointer.
The first parameter of the function provides a pointer to the struct. This parameter is provided as const to prevent the struct members being modified by the function.
MISRA 2023 rule C.11.8 however, does not allow to cast a const pointer to a pointer.
Structure type:
typedef struct {
    uint16          ID;
    int16           *In;
    int16           Out;
    int16           V;
    int8            sfr;
} GAIN_FIP16;

C function:
void* Gain_FiP16_GetAddress(const GAIN_FIP16* block, uint16 elementId)
{
    void* addr;
    switch (elementId)
    {
        case 1:
            addr = (void*)block->In;
            break;
        case 2:
            addr = (void*)&block->Out;
            break;
        default:
            addr = NULL;
            break;
    }
    return (addr);
}

The MISRA checker does complain about the cast (void*)&block->Out.
This violates the MISRA rule:

A conversion shall not remove any const, volatile or _Atomic
qualification from the type pointed to by a pointer.

AFAIK I do have the following possibilities:

Remove the const qualifier of the first function argument (but that also removes the 'nice' read-only behavior)
Create a MISRA deviation

Is there possibly another solution to this problem?
I removed the const qualifier from the block parameter.
This solves the MISRA warning but at the cost of losing the 'read-only' feature.

Do you intend to write to the returned address?  Also, case 1 is returning the value of a member, not the address of a member.

Can the function sensibly return a const void *?  You'd not need the casts then.

@dbush In is type int16* but Out is type int16. That's the reason why I return In1 directly (it is a pointer to the desired data) but have to return the address of Out (because it is a value but not a pointer)

@JonathanLeffler I'd like to avoid returning it as const void*. The calling function does only read from the returned address but the value of In and Out will change.

@Markus If that's intentional then fine.  That just means that what the function is doing appears inconsistent.

Recent question has slightly similar issues: How do I pass a head-tail linked list to a function immutably? Having: const GAIN_FIP16* block does not prevent the function from doing: *block->In = 37;

@dbush yes, this behavior is desired. But I can understand that it is quite confusing without context (or the rest of the software). I also must admit, that the question is slightly incorrect because the the function does not get and return the member addresses but does return the address to the desired data of members In and Out.

@CraigEstey correct. Because of this I'm thinking about removing the const qualifier. My intention of using the const qualifier was to indicate to a caller that the function does not intend to modify the member elements.

You said: I'd like to avoid returning it as const void *. The calling function does only read from the returned address but the value of In and Out will change. I don't see why that's a problem — can you explain?

It sounds like you may suppose that C makes some kind of guarantee on which a compiler could rely to assume that the value of the object pointed to by a pointer to const data will not change between accesses.  That is not the case.

That is true for case 1 but case 2 is where the breakage is happening. Out is a scalar and In is a pointer!? If Out were a pointer, you could eliminate the casts and return an int16 * and nobody's clams are left in the sun too long :-)

Would void const* as the return value and GAIN_FIP16 const* work?  This would mean the pointer is a const, not the value it is pointing to.

@cup void const* and const void* is the same thing. As for void* const you can't assign that to point at a const type*, same problem as the OP is already having.

@JonathanLeffler Maybe I am wrong but if I return the value as const void*, the compiler might do wrong optimizations in the calling function. For example: A function, that calls getAddress gets the pointer (to const) and uses it to continuously fetch data from that pointer. Because it is const void*, the compiler might assume, that the value at this address cannot change and uses a (register) cached value instead of fetching data from that memory address.

@Markus The compiler can only do such optimizations if it can deduct that the actual declaration of the object is indeed a read-only one. Otherwise a const-qualified pointer may be an alias of a non-qualified variable of the same type. Consider int a; ... void f (const int*x) { printf("%d", *x); a=1; if(*x == y) ... } At *x == y, the compiler must reload the value of *x from memory and not use the register utilized by the printf call. Because it cannot assume that a=1; did not modify *x.

@Markus, I already addressed exactly that concern in my earlier comment. No, the spec does not make any provision on which a compiler could rely to justify such an optimization.  You cannot modify the pointed-to data via a pointer to const, but that does not imply that it cannot be modified at all.  Compilers know this.  But if you want to really emphasize it then you can make use a pointer to const volatile.  With that, C requires a fresh read for every access even if the compiler doesn't think there's any possibility that the data have changed.

void* is rarely ever the correct solution to any problem these days. And "casting away const" is not only problematic in a MISRA perspective but also in standard C where you risk invoking undefined behavior in case the value is de-referenced and written to later. Why the MISRA rule exists to begin with.
The obvious solution is to rewrite the function so that it returns a const int16* as it ought to have done in the first place. You should also get rid of "home-brewed" standards in favour of standard C and use int16_t from stdint.h.
const int16_t* Gain_FiP16_GetAddress (const GAIN_FIP16* block, uint16_t elementId)
{
    const int16_t* addr;

    switch (elementId)
    {
        case 1:  addr = block->In;   break;
        case 2:  addr = &block->Out; break;
        default: addr = NULL;        break;
    }
    return addr;
}


You are correct. It is not a nice solution and we're currently thinking about doing a re-organization of this concept. But that's a far greater 'construction site' requiring a lot more effort. The reason why the return value has to be void* is that this is not the only GetAddress function but there are several blocks (C files) that can have different data types for their Input- and Output members. All these blocks use a common void* GetAddress(const void*, uint16 elementId) function type.
We are also planning on replacing the 'custom types' by the standard C types.

@Markus Consider doing that with modern C instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78709467/why-do-c-generics-use-void-instead-of-macros/78710036#78710036. MISRA C:2023 has support for _Generic.
